# How to add a portable database to an MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project, plus a class library project, that I am planning on open-sourcing. Before I do that though I want to clean up the project a little bit. One modification I want to make is with the database. Currently the site is published to a shared hosting server and I setup the SQL database on that server. However, since people will be forking the project and running it locally I'd like to just attach a SQL server express database or something that is part of the project. I want people to clone the repository, open the project, press F5 and have it run. Currently they'd have to setup a SQL database and create all the tables and stuff.

The solution consists of two projects: MvcUI and Domain. Domain is where all the application logic occurs. In fact, the domain is UI agnostic which means that it could be consumed by a desktop application just as easily as it could be by a web application.

I would like the database to be part of the Domain (class library) project. I have never done this before. If anyone could provide a simple explanation for how I would need to go about setting this up I would be thrilled. It would be very nice to have the database just be a in the solution because I could pre-populate it with some basic data. What do I need to do to get this database in my project as a database file or what not?

Comment: @jrummell Please explain, I'm very interested.

Comment: I added an answer with some more information.

Comment: Chosing SQlite instead of SQL CE will make it cross platform - working on .Net/Windows, Mono/OSX and Mono/Linux - the class lib even on Mono/Android and Mono/IOS

Comment: @EugenRieck I may do that. Currently though, my extensive use of Entity Framework limits me from being able to run on Mono :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876) is a portable SQL database that should do exactly what you are asking.

> Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 is a free, embedded database that
>   software developers can use for building ASP.NET websites and Windows
>   desktop applications. SQL Server Compact 4.0 has a small footprint and
>   supports private deployment of its binaries within the application
>   folder, easy application development in Visual Studio and WebMatrix,
>   and seamless migration of schema and data to SQL Server.

Comment: And it is Windows only - so using SQL CE will make it impossible for the class libe to work on OSX/iOS/Linux/Android

Comment: So do I just add a SQL CE db to my class library project? How does that work at runtime and all that?

Comment: Given that the OP is asking in regards to an ASP.NET web site, he should be OK with Windows OS.

Comment: Also, I see options for multiple databases when I add new item to project. Do I want SQL Server Compact 4.0 Local Database or do I want Local Database? Local Database says "An empty SQL Server Compact Edition database for local data.

http://www.codetunnel.com/content/images/sqlce.jpg

Comment: I haven't used SQlite so I can't really compare it to SQL CE. But you are right, if Mono is a concern, SQL CE will not work for you.

Comment: @AlexFord it's been a while, but I believe you want the SQL Server Company 4.0 Local Database.

Comment: @EugenRieck I use Entity Framework though, which is not currently supported on Mono. I checked.

Comment: Are you able to add SQL CE to a class library?

Comment: No, you'll want to add the database to your ASP.NET project. You can store the connection string in your library though.